# How can i create an Angular directive that accepts parameter in the name of directive itself?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a directive which accepts parameter in it's name itself ? 
For Eg. I want

```
<my-directive = "myparameter"></my-directive>
```

not something like

```
<my-directive parameter-name="myparameter"></my-directive>
```

Please explain how can i achieve that with Isolated Scope as

Comment: i have not seen that format. what about `<div my-directive='test'></div>`
Please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/vunb/8gut9mjb/1/

Comment: @VuBaoNhu How can i do that without creating a scope.
( Something like ngModel )

Comment: it has used same `ngModel`. here `test` is model in your controller. you can find more document here to fits your need: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: @VuBaoNhu But your jsfiddle example creates a new scope and as far as i know ngModel does not create a new scope.

Comment: i guess you want to access directly scope of parents ? if so you can get directive params via `attrs` and now default 'scope = true` and then it uses scope of parents directly. do you want this ? http://jsfiddle.net/vunb/8gut9mjb/4/

Comment: @VuBaoNhu Thanks , I didn't knew u can read mind. Btw Is this exactly how ngModel and input directive works together ?

Comment: I think so. if you are interested, please dig into [ngModel](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/9130166767c4792c5d32d08a918fc7becf32c9a6/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L245) it has tons of code.

Answer (score 0):

Those listed below are the alternatives to make an angular dierctive(EAMC)
I don`t think you can create a directive as you mention above unless you modify the angularDirective source.May be the example will help.

---

> HTML

---

```
<div ng-app="app">
      <my-directive param="'**element**'"></my-directive>

      <div my-directive="" param="'attribute'"></div>

      <div>
           <!-- directive: my-directive **comment** -->    
      </div>

      <div class="my-directive: **class**;"></div>
</div>


    var app = angular.module('app', []);

***
```

> JS

---

```
app.directive('my-directive', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EAMC',
        template: '<div>Directive from {{param}}!</div>',
        scope: {
            loc: '='
        },
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            if (attrs.my-directive) {
                scope.loc = attrs.my-directive;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: did you forget that directive definitions use camelCase?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with something like:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {'myDirective': '='}, // this won't actually do the binding, but is here for code-clarity
        link: function(scope, elem, attr){
            // here is where we actually bind the data
            attr.$observe('myDirective', function(myDirective){
                // since the attribute is observed as a string, $eval it on the $parent scope
                // (note that without isolate scope, you could do scope.$eval(myDirective)
                scope.myDirective = scope.$parent.$eval(myDirective);
            });
        }
    };
});
```